# Fragment loses its state when rotate device twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which displays two fragments:

- When activity is created, it displays `Fragment1`.
- When the user presses the button on `Fragment1`, it displays `Fragment2`, adding to backstack.

Fragments are straightforward. `Fragment1` contains `CheckBox` and `EditText`. `Fragment2` contains simple `TextView`. Also I call `setRetainInstance(true)` in fragment's `onCreate(...)` method.

**Problem**: `Fragment1` loses its state if `Fragment2` is displayed and device is rotated **twice**. However, everything works as expected if device is rotate only **once**.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Launch application.
2. Check `CheckBox` and type some text into `EditText`
3. Press `Button` to launch `Fragment2`
4. Rotate device
5. Rotate device once again
6. Press `Back` button on your device (or `ESC` on Emulator) to return back to `Fragment1`

`Fragment1` lost its state (checkbox is unchecked and `EditText` is empty).
However, if you return back to `Fragment1` after `step#4` - `Fragment1` keeps its state as expected.

Where is the problem? All code is below, including layouts.

**main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**fragment1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Fragment2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment2.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment #2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentTestActivity.java**:

```
package fragmenttest.example.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FragmentTestActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.TAG) == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, new Fragment1(), Fragment1.TAG).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(Fragment2.TAG) == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, new Fragment2(), Fragment2.TAG).addToBackStack(Fragment2.TAG).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java**:

```
package fragmenttest.example.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = Fragment1.class.getName();
    private FragmentListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onButtonClick();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        mListener = (FragmentListener) activity;
    }
}
```

**Fragment2.java**:

```
package fragmenttest.example.com;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = Fragment2.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        return root;
    }
}
```

**FragmentListener.java**:

```
package fragmenttest.example.com;

public interface FragmentListener {
    public void onButtonClick();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because onCreate isn't called when restoring the fragment.
See:[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Comment: Yes, your are right! As documentation says, "*This (setRetainInstance) can only be used with fragments not in the back stack.*"